# Using data() function of jquery form nested data for DOM

Tags: jquery

I am looking form a nested data to a DOM element. Something like this

```
$("div").data( "test", { 
    first: 16,
    last: "pizza!"
});
```

Here is my effort to make similar kind of format. But RefAttrValue variable is not behaving as variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < reference.attributes.length; i++) {
    var RefAttrValue = (reference.attributes.item(i).name);
    $(tableCaption).data("referenceData").RefAttrValue = reference.attributes.item(i).value;
}
```

Here the Values of the "reference" is a XML. Which has value like below or can contain any similar XML.

```
<facilityreference Name="qtitem_fac" AttrTable='table1' colVal='table1colValue'></facilityreference>
```

I want to set up the `data()` format in this below format **"Dynamically"**.

```
$("div").data("test",{ Name: "qtitem_fac", last: "table1colValue" });
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need something like this:

```
var datObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < reference.attributes.length; i++) {
    var RefAttrValue = (reference.attributes.item(i).name);
    datObj[RefAttrValue] = reference.attributes.item(i).value;
}
$(tableCaption).data("referenceData", datObj );
```

In your code I see few problems:
First: If you do nothing like `$(tableCaption).data("referenceData", {...})` before you run your code, line `$(tableCaption).data("referenceData")` will return undefined and that will cause an exception.

If you have a field name in a variable (`RefAttrValue` in your case) you need to do something like `$(tableCaption).data("referenceData")[RefAttrValue]`. Such notation is a synonym, if `RefAttrValue = "Name"`, to `$(tableCaption).data("referenceData").Name`

Doing this `$(tableCaption).data("referenceData").RefAttrValue` you simply access property of referenceData with name `RefAttrValue`.

Comment: How can I access the above stored data ? Will it be something like this ? $(tableCaption).data("referenceData").datObjValue; ?

Comment: Using your example, it will be `$(tableCaption).data("referenceData").Name`

Answer (score 1):

Not tested:

```
 obj = {};

    $('facilityreference').each(function(){
       $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
           obj[attrib.name] = attrib.value;
      });

    }); // then do something with you object
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use this...Hopefully this will solve the requirement.!
str = $('#id').data('test');var json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + str + ")"));alert(json);
```